# How do I add a folder value to a command?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch

I'm trying to get a simple batch file to work.

```
set locDir="C:\Users\jp2code\My Projects\VS\Live\Mainframe\DataFactory\AppServerLib\"
notepad.exe locDir+readMe.txt
ECHO Complete!
```

When I run the `test.bat` batch file, I get a MessageBox from Notepad that says, *"Cannot find the locDir+readMe.txt file."*

It has been too long since I worked with DOS style batch processes.

Could someone refresh me on how to do this?

If this info is out on the internet, I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set locDir=C:\Users\jp2code\My Projects\VS\Live\Mainframe\DataFactory\AppServerLib\
notepad.exe %locDir%readMe.txt
ECHO Complete!
```

- You have to use `%` symbols with variables
- The `+` symbol isn't there for concatenating
- If you use double quotes, you have to remove them afterwards. In my quick example I replaced them.

Comment: Quotes are wrong, but that did it. Thanks!

Comment: This example won't work if your path contains `&` symbols. Its always a mess with them.

Comment: Got it. This is just to help me do some local file manipulation, so I promise not to use the Ampersand (`&`).

Comment: Finish this sentence: This answer has had more edits than a ...